# PHP and JSON output with and without key

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a weird bug, and uncertain what causes it. Perhaps there is an error somewhere in my code.

This is the JSON that PHP (via Ajax) sends to the browser for JQuery to use, and this is the correct way, and how i want it.

```
{"response":"success","comment":"<strong>Done.<\/strong> Your details has been updated.","id":"4","images":[{"Image":"\/cache\/Products\/picture.jpg"},{"Image":"\/cache\/Products\/picture2.jpg"}]}
```

But the odd occasion i get the following:

```
{"response":"success","comment":"<strong>Done.<\/strong> Your details has been updated.","id":"4","images":{"1": {"Image":"\/cache\/Products\/picture.jpg"},"2":{"Image":"\/cache\/Products\/picture2.jpg"}}}
```

The Images JSON array changes! Yet they both use the same code.

This is the PHP case, that Ajax calls.

```
case 'removeImages':    
            $id = fixText($user, $_GET['id'],0,0,0);
            $elm = fixText($user, $_POST['elm'],0,0,0);
            $uploadTo = fullPath;
            $result = mysqli_query($user, "SELECT productImages FROM hireProducts WHERE `id`='$id'");
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
                $get = (array) json_decode($row['productImages'], true);
                $filename = $uploadTo.$get[$elm]['Image'];
                if (file_exists($filename)) {
                    unlink($filename);
                }
                unset($get[$elm]);

                $jsonImages = json_encode($get);            
                $update = mysqli_query($user, "UPDATE hireProducts SET `productImages` = '$jsonImages' WHERE `id`='$id'");
                if ($update) {                  
                        $arr = array('response'=>'success','comment'=>A01, 'id'=>$id, 'images'=>$get);
                } else {
                        $arr = array('response'=>'error','comment'=>A001.'AL001');              
                }
            } else {
                $arr = array('response'=>'error','comment'=>A003);                  
            } 
            echo json_encode($arr);  
            exit;
        break;
```

All i want is for it to always to be the same (the first one).
Thanks

Comment: have you checked whats inside `$row['productImages'],` in the different calls?

Comment: I found the issue! If i delete an item say with a key 0, then json returns with 1 and 2, its not in order. so i did $get = array_values($get); and its fixed it

Comment: @Sickaaron sorry, could you rephrase it? So by just deleting a key/value pair you would get consistent (key wise) array? IMHO just a temporary coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

if i had an array `0...4` and say i deleted `4`, the JSON array would be correct. But if i deleted say `0`, then JSON would have `1, 2, 3` and resulted in the bug i was seeing.

So i simply just reindexed the array before i sent it with:

```
$get = array_values($get);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [json.org](http://json.org):

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Thus the order is not distinct. You can do `ksort` on the encoded JSON array (supposing `$get` is the array of images, ascending sort):

```
ksort($get);
```